# How to optimize this makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to optimize this makefile for adding PGM.

I created `makefile` needs to be optimized:

```
SOURCES = main.cpp logic.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
CC = CC
MODEL001 = FLAGA FLAGB
MODEL002 = FLAGC
CFLAGS001 = -c $(MODEL001:%=-D%)
CFLAGS002 = -c $(MODEL002:%=-D%)
PGMNUM = 001 002

all: PGM001 PGM002

PGM001:$(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS001) $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) -o $PGM001 $(OBJECTS)

PGM002:$(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS002) $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) -o $PGM002 $(OBJECTS)
```

Currently, I change the following variables when adding a PGM003.

```
ADD : MODEL003, CFLAGS003, PGM003:$(SOURCES)...
MODIFY : PGMNUM, all
```

Just by adding `MODEL003` and `PGMNUM`, this makefile seems to work. How can I do it?

(pseudo code like this but does not work):

```
SOURCES = main.cpp logic.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
CC = CC
MODEL001 = FLAGA FLAGB
MODEL002 = FLAGC
MODEL003 = FLAGD FLAGE

PGMNUM = 001 002 003

CFLAGS$(PGMNUM) = -c $(MODEL$(PGMNUM):%=-D%)

all: $(PGMNUM:%=PGM%)

PGM$(PGMNUM):$(SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS$(PGMNUM)) $(SOURCES)
    $(CC) -o $PGM$(PGMNUM) $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate your question. How can you do what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'optimize', I take it you want to make it use less lines of code, rather than make it run faster.  If so, you can use a function and eval as so:

```
SOURCES := main.cpp logic.cpp
PGMNUMS := 001 002 003
CC := CC

MODEL001 := FLAGA FLAGB
MODEL002 := FLAGC
MODEL003 := FLAGD

define func

CFLAGS$1 := -c $(MODEL$(p):%=-D%)
OBJECTS$1 := $$(SOURCES:.cpp=.$1.o)

$$(OBJECTS$1) : %.$1.o : %.cpp
        $(CC) $$(CFLAGS$1) -o $$@ $$^

PGM$1 : $$(OBJECTS$1)
        $(CC) -o $$@ $$^

endef


$(info --vv--  show generated code --vv--)
$(foreach p,$(PGMNUMS),$(info $(call func,$p)))
$(info --^^-- end of generated code --^^--)

#actually generate the calls:
$(foreach p,$(PGMNUMS),$(eval $(call func,$p)))

all: $(PGMNUM:%=PGM%)
```

Basically, you define a function `func`, and then run it for all values of `$(PGMNUMS)`.   Notice the use of `$$` in the function definition -- in the function, `$1` will expand to the first parameter.   Items with `$$var` in front of them will expand to `$var`, rather than expanding at the time.   I added a `$(info..)` which is useful to debug what you generate.

Comment: I have 2 questions :
1. makefile:28: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
 I got this error(line : $(foreach p,$(PGMNUMS),$(eval $(call func,$p))) )

2. There is also a Sun OS server, so I can't define `func'. Is it possible to make Makefile Optimize(just reduce lines of code)?

Comment: In the define, you need to use tabs to indent the recipe lines rather than spaces (it's a common issue when cutting and pasting from stackoverflow).    As far as not being able to define func -- are you using eMake on the SunOs?

Comment: 1. there is no tab in 28th line(this line) :
$(foreach p,$(PGMNUMS),$(eval $(call func,$p)))
2. It is SunOS make but not eMake. According man(make)
 :  SunOS 5.10          Last change: 20 Sep 2010

Comment: The missing tab comes from the expansion of `func` -- the recipe lines (2 of them) defined in `func` should begin with tabs (both lines beginning with `$(CC)` should have tabs.   If you want to do this without eval, you could write a makefile to generate another makefile, and then do a recursive call to make...   This is quite convoluted though  (or alternatively you could install gnu make on your system, and call it explicitly...)

Comment: Thanks! Since I think that make another makefile is too complex, I'm going to make a program which makes that makefile.(I can't install gnu make because the server is not mine). I've been studying a lot!